# jQuery: find all <a> and modify them, probably missing 'this' somewhere

Tags: jquery, selector

Basically I need to find each  element in a website, that has a specific node value in it. Add a .roll class to each , and add a new  inside the node.

Here's an example of what I want to do, and what is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zuax/2/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 4</a>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

JS:

```
// add .red to each <a> element
$('a').addClass('red');
// add a new <span> child into each found <a> element, but with the current <a>'s html();
$('a').html("<span data-title="+$('a').text()+">"+$('a').html()+"</span>");

// Why does all of the links have 'link 1' instead of 'link 1...2...3...4' ? ---->
```

RESULT:
link 1 link 1 link 1 link 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `each` to apply some code to each element but the most direct is to pass a callback to `html` :

```
$('a').html(function(_,h){
     return '<span data-title="'+$(this).text()+'">'+h+'</span>';
});
```

Comment: +1 but why do you say it is the best? Each loop e.g should be faster

Comment: It's the most direct solution. I don't see why using `each` would be faster, it does about the same thing.

Comment: just a question - what is that first parameter (`_`) in the function? whats the use of that?

Comment: @hungerpain The callback takes two parameters. The first one, which isn't used here, is the index. I took the habit to make obvious the parameter isn't used by calling it `_`. I could have called it `i`, that's just a name. It's also a reminder of the `_` placeholder that you have in some other languages.

Comment: okay.. but this will work without any parameters : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/7Zuax/3/
whats the necessiy in having it ? @dystroy

Comment: You are right, most direct way for sure and when i say faster i speak about nanoseconds which no one cares

Comment: @hungerpain using the directly provided `h` argument is much faster (and simple) than using `$(this).html()`.

Comment: @dystroy thanks a lot :) gosh! everyday you learn something over here :)

Comment: Please, inspect your results and see how the <span> has been generated!

Comment: @MarcinBauer Is the last fix I made somewhat related to your cryptic comment ?

Comment: @dystroy just checked and in this case html() is faster, my bad.

Comment: Thank you @dystroy and rest :) Works great! I have to come here often... to ask and help if I can :)